# matplotlib secondary_xaxis() function doesn't work

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was looking for ways to make a plot with two x-axis and I was very happy to found the `secondary_xaxis(`) function on https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/secondary_axis.html. I read the description and had a look at the code and then I decided to simply download the whole thing (as a Jupyter notebook) and try it out.
However, even though I didn't make any changes to the code, it didn't work. I simply got the following error directly for the first plot:

```
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'secondary_xaxis'
```

I really don't understand why and how this error comes up as I just downloaded the code from the website. I also tried to copy and paste it from the website, but of course the result didn't change as the code is the same.

Comment: Check your matplotlib version. This feature is introduced in versions 3.1 and above. Most likely you have a lower version than 3.1

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to check for updates. That was the problem and now it works.